# Copying files to tablet with Android

Tags: file-transfer, files

When I copy `file.pdf` to my tablet with the command (in Linux - Ubuntu)
`cp file.pdf /media/Archos_7/Data` via USB cable and then disconnect USB and look to the Data directory, `file.pdf` has size 0 B, or the file is not there (e.g. `file.epub`). I don't know what is wrong. I copied a few `*.pdf` and `*.avi` files successfully.

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Now, I copied three files - file.avi, file.pdf and file.epub to the Archos_7/Video folder. file.avi is copied OK, file.pdf is copied but has size 0 B, file.epub is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your device auto-mount its storage to the PC when connected?  On most devices you need to pull down the notification bar and click the USB notification to mount.  You should dismount the same way, after dismounting in Linux, before unplugging the device.

And, how much free space do you have?

Comment: Now the device is mounted twice (according to cat /etc/mtab) /dev/sdc /media/ARCHOS\0407 vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=hal,uid=1000,umask=0077,shortname=winnt,utf8 0 0
/dev/sdd /media/ARCHOS\0407_ vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=hal,uid=1000,umask=0077,shortname=winnt,utf8 0 0

Comment: In Internal flash storage I have 2 GB and in Internal device storage I have 414 MB Available space

Comment: It was needed to `umount`.